# Sql query returns only one row (LIKE)

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers
WHERE Firstname LIKE  'George'
```

The problem is that i have more than 1 rows in the table with tha name Geoge and the result of the query shows only one row

Comment: what's your collation and charset?

Comment: @swasheck Rum and coke.

Answer (score 5):

You will want to include the wildcard `%` character to include the rows the have `George` present in the name:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers
WHERE Firstname LIKE  '%George%';
```

If `George` will always appear at the beginning, then you can include the wildcard on the end:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers
WHERE Firstname LIKE  'George%';
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to add a wildcard character `%` to match any value that contains `george`

```
SELECT * 
FROM   customers
WHERE  Firstname LIKE  '%George%'
```

- [MySQL LIKE Operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

the statement

```
WHERE  Firstname LIKE  'George'
```

is equivalent with

```
WHERE  Firstname =  'George'
```

that is why you are only getting one record which firstname is `george`.

**UPDATE 1**

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0aaef6/3)

Comment: `LIKE` without wildcards is not 100% equivalent to `=`. See: **[`LIKE` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)**

Comment: @ypercube Not to mention that an index won't be used if there's a left sided wildcard.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO My point was only about comparing `=` with (`LIKE` without wildcards.)

Answer (score -2):

try

```
LOWER(Firstname) LIKE '%george%'
```

handles partial values and avoids case sensietivity issues.

Comment: I think most DB's are case insensitive.

Comment: @Sundeep is correct you don't have to worry about case sensitivity.